# If a permanent is tapped, are enchantments on it also tapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have a Forest in play enchanted with [Utopia Sprawl](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUtopia%20Sprawl%5d). Opponent has a [Mesmeric Orb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMesmeric%20Orb%5d) in play, which has this text:

> Whenever a permanent becomes untapped, that permanent's controller mills a card.

On my turn I tap the Forest for mana. On my next turn when the Forest untaps, do I mill one card or two?

Intuitively I'm guessing one card, but I'm not aware of any rule that says it should be one card, so I'd like to check.

Comment: While most people physically tap the entire stack of auras and equipment/fortifications along with creatures/lands when they tap them, it's actually incredibly rare for equipment and auras to tap - it's just done visibly for convenience but not done mechanically.

Comment: @Andrew It's a good thing, then, that the game rarely cares about tapped enchantments. Tapped artifacts are slightly worse. But if you're ever in such a situation, you can make the extra physical effort then. Now I'm suddenly curious how this is done in official high-end tournaments.

Comment: @Arthur those tournaments, at least tge later games, are often streamed. Itcwouldnt be hard to find footage on say YouTube and check.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah I'm quite sure it's easy to figure out. It's mostly just a question that struck me as I wrote the comment.

Comment: For a while, I ran an [improvise](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Improvise) deck with equipment. I could attack with an equipped creature and then later tap the equipment to cast another spell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, each permanent individually can be tapped or untapped; tapping or untapping a permanent does not tap or untap any enchantments on it. Similarly, tapping or untapping an aura enchantment does not affect the permanent it is enchanting.

> 110.5. A permanent’s status is its physical state. There are four status categories, each of which has two possible values: tapped/untapped, flipped/unflipped, face up/face down, and phased in/phased out. Each permanent always has one of these values for each of these categories.

Comment: Of course, it would be an absolutely confusing mechanic for a designer to put a tap mechanic on an Aura or Equipment... But still, it would be possible, and I'm sure there are some cases where it matters.

Comment: They actually did it with https://scryfall.com/card/fut/113/flowstone-embrace

Comment: Ah, Future Sight.  The gift that keeps on giving.  :D

Comment: Second Wind too

Comment: Improvise is the "tap mechanic for Equipment" (more because it's an artifact than it's equipment, but still).  It was important to have independent tapping of the creature and the Equipment (even when the creature was also an artifact).